# How do I install gstreamer(gst lib) on Arch linux

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, archlinux

I get this error:

```
    [k4li@madison gst]$ gcc basic-tutorial-1.c 
basic-tutorial-1.c:1:21: fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gst/gst.h>
```

but I installed gstreamer and all the plugins on my Arch machine.

```
sudo pacman -S --needed $(pacman -Ssq gstreamer)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you also install the dev packages?

Comment: yeah.. and then use pkg-config as stated in tutorial..

Comment: I installed all available packages

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have CFLAGS and LDFLAGS for compiling and linking to the streamer libraries. It should be something like this:

`` gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` basic-tutorial-1.c ``

Your example file sounds like it was from http://gstreamer.com. This is from the old "0.10" branch of gstreamer and is several years unmaintained. Current version is "1.8.2". This site is currently not the best resource for gstreamer development.

You may be lucky by exchanging gstreamer-1.0 with gstreamer-0.10 at the above command when your system still supports these libraries.

Comment: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/ is the official site with good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

install gstreamer:

```
sudo pacman -S gstreamer
```

make it useful,you need install the plugins packeages you require:

- gst-libav
- gst-plugins-bad
- gst-plugins-base
- gst-plugins-good
- gst-plugins-ugly

etc

for more information,read the wiki for [gstreamer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GStreamer) in archwiki.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I installed all available packages

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the fatal error you need to install the package `pkgconf` in Arch linux:

```
sudo pacman -S pkgconf
```